# How to use the DECLARE variables in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert and retrieve the inserted row something like this:

```
DECLARE @ultimo int;

INSERT INTO pv_mensaje
(
reporte ,
tipo_emisor ,
emisor ,
tipo_receptor,
receptor,
mensaje,
registro


)  VALUES (1158,'cliente',6,'',0,'MMMM' ,GETDATE())  ;
SET @ultimo = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
SELECT * FROM pv_mensaje WHERE id = (@ultimo)
```

But send me this error:

Error report -
Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 22 '=' character expected.

Comment: You should edit your question and show us where line position 22 is.

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis ```WHERE id = @ultimo```

Comment: Parenthesis are fine, just aren't needed... there's something else wrong.

Comment: Until we know where the syntax error actually is, this can't be answered.

Comment: Also, I would use a transaction if I wanted to get the scope_identity()

Comment: Why do you need the ultimo variable in the first place? Just say where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Or even simpler....just select a hard coded list of values like you did in the insert statement. It seems a little odd to need to pull data from the table when all the values are hardcoded in the line above.

Comment: The message about invalid JDBC escape seqence indicates that you should be looking for curly brackets in your code.

Comment: Well,  Thanks for the help but i look for other way

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @ultimo int;

INSERT INTO pv_mensaje
(
reporte ,
tipo_emisor ,
emisor ,
tipo_receptor,
receptor,
mensaje,
registro


)  VALUES (1158,'cliente',6,'',0,'MMMM' ,GETDATE())  ;
SET @ultimo = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

Set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM pv_mensaje WHERE id = ('+ @ultimo +')'
Exec (@sql)
```

or:

```
DECLARE @ultimo int;

    INSERT INTO pv_mensaje
    (
    reporte ,
    tipo_emisor ,
    emisor ,
    tipo_receptor,
    receptor,
    mensaje,
    registro


    )  VALUES (1158,'cliente',6,'',0,'MMMM' ,GETDATE())  ;
    SET @ultimo = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
   SELECT * FROM pv_mensaje WHERE id =  @ultimo
```

Comment: The `Exec (sql)` should include the variable declared. `Exec (@sql)`

Comment: Please explain why dynamic SQL is needed for this query.  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: i think its ok but send me the same error i`m looking for other client

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
SELECT  @ultimo = SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```

now your declared variable  will be set to the value.

and then

```
Set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM pv_mensaje WHERE id = ('+ @ultimo +')'
Exec (@sql)
```

Comment: what's with everyone using dynamic SQL when it's not needed?

Comment: Working a lot on procedures these days. 
My bad. 
Yeah it's not needed for this scenario :)

Comment: @Lamak cause they all want to be like little bobby tables! It's what all the kool kids are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it's MS SQL Server.  This is another alternative

```
DECLARE @ultimo_tbl TABLE ( ID INT );

CREATE TABLE #pv_mensaje
    (
      reporte INT IDENTITY ,
      tipo_emisor INT ,
      emisor INT ,
      tipo_receptor INT ,
      receptor INT ,
      mensaje INT ,
      registro INT
    );



INSERT  INTO #pv_mensaje
        ( reporte ,
          emisor ,
          tipo_receptor ,
          tipo_emisor ,
          receptor ,
          mensaje ,
          registro
        )
OUTPUT  Inserted.reporte
        INTO @ultimo_tbl
VALUES  ( 1 ,
          1 ,
          1 ,
          1 ,
          1 ,
          1
        );


SELECT  *
FROM    #pv_mensaje  WHERE pv.reporte IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @ultimo_tbl);
```

Comment: the question is tagged with [sql-server], so, yeah, it is specified